# Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate) when creating navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a simple navigation between login and signup but I get "TypeError : undefined is not an object evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate'). I don't really understand why.

Code below :

SwitchNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from '../screens/Login'
import Signup from '../screens/Signup'
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
      Login: {
          screen: Login
      },
      Signup: {
          screen: Signup
      },
      Profile: {
          screen: Profile
      }
  },
  {
      initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native'

class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.jungleText}>Jungle</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                    placeholder='Email'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputBox}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                  placeholder='Password'
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              <Button
                title="Don't have an account yet? Sign up"
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}
              />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Thanks a lot for helping me !

Comment: Can you please console this.props on button click

Comment: @mainak I get an empty object

Comment: Then navigator is not correctly set up. You will get callbacks including navigation in console of this.props

Comment: I have no idea how to configure navigator

Comment: Try with the following answer added by me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, paste this in your navigator page, and install -> npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view

```
import React from "react";
import {
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
} from "react-navigation";
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import Signup from "../screens/Signup";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
  },
});

const SignupStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Signup,
  },
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Profile,
  },
});

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginStack,
    Signup: SignupStack,
    Profile: ProfileStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Login",
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);
```

Comment: I copied/pasted, it doesn't change anything, same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Javascript or react native, you'll come across this error a lot. This happens when you try to get access inner object/property using '.' on a null object. In this case `this.props.navigation` is null and hence `this.props.navigation.navigate` will give this error.

A simple solution, export your Login component like this:

```
export default withNavigation(Login)
```

Make sure to import withNavigation

```
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation"
```

Explaination: [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/with-navigation/) is simply a Higher order component that make sure navigation prop is available to your Login component.

Answer (score 0):

change your class components to function components. then pass navigation as an argument the function component. Then use useState hook to handle your states. Lemme know if this works